# Why am I getting "userID is not defined"

Tags: javascript, google-workspace

Could you please help me with the following script? I'm getting "userID is not defined".

I'm trying to bulk modify licenses based on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e4KTAytOeyA

```
function updateLicenses() {
    var updateSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive() .getSheetByName("Update Licenses")
    var data = updateSheet.getRange(2, 1, updateSheet.getLastRow() - 1, 3).getValues()
  var fileArray = [
        ["License Update Status"]
    ]


    // Loop through all user provided google sheet rows and call Directy API with it

    data.forEach(function(item) {
        var status = "License Assigned Successfully"
        try {
            var userId = item[0]
            var apiCall = AdminLicenseManager.LicenseAssignments.patch({
          
            // enter new license details here
                "productID": "Google-Apps",
                "skuID": "1010020027",
                "userID": userID
           }, "Google-Apps", "1010020028", userId)  // enter exiting/assigned license details here
              
      } catch (e) {
          var status = e.message
      }
      fileArray.push([status])
    })
      
    updateSheet.getRange(1, 2, fileArray.length, fileArray[0].length).setValues(fileArray)

    //AdminLicenseManager.LicenseAssignments.patch()
}
```

Comment: Where was `userID` defined?

Answer (score 0):

Based on that video. Did you rename the tap of the Sheet as `Update Licenses`?

[image]

Are the user IDs in column A, as shown in the video, or a different Column? (if you change the column for the emails, is the var `data` pointing to that column?)

I searched on [the page](https://www.goldyarora.com/bulk-assign-frontline/) of the owner of the video, and he updated his code:

```
function assignLicenses() {

    // Add SKU details here, below ones are for frontline worker
    var productId = "Google-Apps"
    var skuId = 1010020030

    // Get Google Sheet and read the user emails from it, we'll use these to assign licenses

    var assignmentSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Assign Frontline Licenses")
    var data = assignmentSheet.getRange(2, 1, assignmentSheet.getLastRow() - 1, 2).getValues()

    // Create an array to store the results from API, instead of appendRow, we'll rather save output to this array, and then write back to sheet at once
    var fileArray = [
        ["License Assignment Status"]
    ]

    // Loop through the google sheet values, and call License API to assign the given license
    data.forEach(function(item) {
        var status = "Licese Assigned Successfully"
        try {
            //var productId = getSkuDetails(item[1])
            var apiCall = AdminLicenseManager.LicenseAssignments.insert({
                "userId": item[0]
            }, productId, skuId)
        }

        // Catch Errors (if any)
        catch (e) {
            var status = e.message
        }

        // Write the output data back to our array
        fileArray.push([status])
    })


    // Write the results from array to our google sheet
    assignmentSheet.getRange(1, 2, fileArray.length, fileArray[0].length).setValues(fileArray)
}
```

Let me know if you have questions.